# TPM messages are flooding my event viewer

Tags: windows, event-viewer, tpm

I am trying to troubleshoot a Windows 10 Pro system.  This is complicated by the fact that the system event log is flooded by a set of identical information level messages about TPM every minute.

The messages are:

1. The TPM has been cleared. Reason: ByPPI.
2. The Ownership of the Trusted Platform Module (TPM) hardware on this computer was
   successfully taken (TPM TakeOwnership command) by the system.
3. The TBS device identifier has been generated.
4. The TPM was successfully provisioned and is now ready for use.

I found a TPM-Maintenance task in the task scheduler that seems to run every minute.
Can someone explain why Windows is clearing the TPM once a minute?  Is that necessary?  Can I safely disable the TPM-Maintenance task to prevent this flood of messages?

Thanks!